# AS3 Flash webcam snapshot reduce motion blur?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, webcam

i have a photo snapping app built in flash. I notice that any movement results in a lot of motion blur.. which makes the photos kind of turd.

Is there a way to digital reduce the blur? potential camera setting in actionscript??

Answer (score 1):

Basically to get the shot less blurry you have to reduce the exposure time, so you should set the FPS higher (i believe 30 is the max) and might have to turn the quality down to get the capture quick enough. experiment with the values. have a look [Here](http://blog.728media.com/2009/02/24/actionscript-3-webcam-configure/) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, i stopping streaming from camera object, and working with the last picture which left there. Hope this point you to the right direction. If not i will try to provide you with some code